# Eigenvalue problem for the Laplacian on the unit ball

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

I want to find out what are the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the eigenvalue problem for the Laplacian on the unit ball in $\mathbb R^3$, with the Dirichlet boundary conditions.

Comment: In how many dimensions?  And which boundary conditions?

Comment: three dimensions and Dirichlet boundary conditions

Comment: I think it is described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics

Comment: Some people seem intent on closing down your question.  So I hope you get to read my previous comment before this gets deleted.

Comment: I have seen your comment, thank you. but I couldn't find something precisely about what is eigenvalue and eigenfunction.

Comment: Oops, yes, you are correct.  But maybe if you try the separation of variables technique described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Laplace.27s_spherical_harmonics, maybe it would provide a solution.

Comment: http://www.lulu.com/us/en/shop/nakhl%C3%A9-h-asmar/partial-differential-equations-with-fourier-series-and-boundary-value-problems/hardcover/product-20990743.html Look at Chapter 5.4.  A lot of other books will cover it as well.

Comment: Here as well.  google "Helmholtz spherical bessel function" http://physics.ucsc.edu/~peter/116C/helm_sp.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Write the Laplacian on the unit ball in polar coordinates $(r,\xi)$, with $r\in (0,1],\xi\in S^{n-1}$, and separate variables. The basic form of the eigenfunctions will be
$$ \big(\mbox{generalized Bessel function}\big)(r)\big(\mbox{spherical harmonic}\big)(\xi)$$
where the index of the Bessel function is determined by the Dirichlet condition. You then find the eigenvalues by examining the indices of the Bessel function and the spherical harmonic.

The general case of a ball in a constant-curvature space form is treated similarly, by taking geodesic polar coordinates and separating variables, and can be found in ch 2, section 5 of Chavel's book *Eigenvalues in Riemannian Geometry.*