# Can we show that the normal derivative of the first eigenfunction of $-\Delta$ is negative?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, laplacian, linear-pde

Let $(\lambda_1,e_1)$ denote the first eigenpair of $-\Delta$ on a ball $\Omega:=B_r(0)$ in $\mathbb R^d$, i.e. $\lambda_1>0$ and $e_1\in C^2(\overline\Omega)$ with \begin{align}-\Delta\left. e_1\right|_\Omega&=\lambda_1\left.e_1\right|_\Omega\tag1\\\left.e_1\right|_\Omega&>0\tag2\\\left.e_1\right|_{\partial\Omega}&=0.\tag3\end{align}

> How can we show that the derivative $\partial_\nu e_1$ of $e_1$ in the direction of the unit outer normal field $\nu$ on $\partial\Omega$ is negative?

We can show that $e_1$ is [rotational invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_invariance) and satisfies $$\lambda_1e_1(s)+\frac{n-1}se_1'(s)+e_1''(s)=0\tag4\;\;\;\text{for all }s\in(0,r).$$ Moreover, since $$\langle x,\nabla e_1(x)\rangle=e_1'(\|x\|)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\overline\Omega\tag5,$$ we've got $$\partial_\nu e_1(x)=\langle\nu(x),\nabla e_1(x)\rangle=\frac1r\langle x,\nabla e_1(x)\rangle=\frac1re_1'(r)\tag6.$$

Lastly, since $e_1$ is positive in $\Omega$ and $e_1(R)=0$, it should hold $e_1'(R)\le0$.

> Can we somehow show that $e_1'(R)=0$ is impossible and use this to conclude the desired claim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to prove it.

1. Just use [Hopf lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_lemma).
2. Note that $e_1$ satisfies (4) and $e_1(R)=0$. If $e_1'(R) = 0$ also, then $e_1(s) = 0$ for all $s>0$ by the uniqueness theorem of ODEs.
3. Write $e_1' = f$. Then (4) implies
   $$\tag{1'}  f' = -\frac{n-1}{s} f - \lambda_1 e_1. $$
   This implies
   \begin{align} (s^{n-1} f)' &=  (n-1)s^{n-2} f + s^{n-1} f' \\
   &= (n-1)s^{n-2} f + s^{n-1} \left(-\frac{n-1}{s} f - \lambda_1 e_1 \right) \\
   &= - s^{n-1}\lambda_1 e_1.  
   \end{align}
   Integrating from $0$ to $R$ and use $f(0) = 0$ gives
   $$R^{n-1} f(R) = -\int_0^R \lambda_1 s^{n-1} e_1(s) ds. $$
   Thus $f(R)$ is clearly negative since $\lambda_1>0$, $s^{n-1} e_1\ge 0$ and is not identically zero.

I guess one can also find $e_1$ explicitly and argue directly. Indeed all eigenvalues and eigenfunctions are known in this case. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/613609/629362).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If we add a inhomogeneity to the Dirichlet problem, i.e. consider $u_t=\Delta u+f(u)$, $\left.u\right|_{\partial\Omega}=0$ and assume that $u(0,\;\cdot\;)=u_0$ is rotational invariant, can we somehow show that $u(t,\;\cdot\;)$ remains rotational invariant? I'm not able to come up with a promising approach for this, but I've got the feeling that it's rather trivial to show ...

Comment: @0xbadf00d You have that if there is uniqueness for your Parabolic PDE (I guess some mild conditions on $f$ would suffices). Since $u$ satisfies the PDE iff $u \circ R$ does, where $R$ is any orthogonal matrix.